# primefaces DataTable draggableColumns

Tags: datatable

As soon as you add draggableColumns="true" Filtering textBox is not working properly 
and also resizable is not working properly.

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="tbl"
    value="#{pc_searchJobBean.searchJobVO.jobVOs}"
    emptyMessage="#{commonMsg['noResultFound']}"
    paginatorPosition="bottom" paginator="true" rows="5"
    filteredValue="#{pc_searchJobBean.searchJobVO.filteredVos}">
```

i have to use draggableColumns and filter both.
is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: This is fixed in PrimeFaces 3.5.1, you are probably on an older version.

Comment: I am using PrimeFaces3.5 is this right version?